# not able to convert json in following format

Tags: json

While using third party rest services i am getting a response like this

```
{"boMetaId":"org__ClientOrder","attributes":
 {  
   "clientid":40002712,
   "productid":40002718,
   "clientorderid":1,
   "clientorderdate":"2017-01-01",
    "clientordervalue":23 
  }
}
```

But i need to convert this json like this while sending data to database

```
{"boMetaId":"org__ClientOrder","attributes":
 {
   "clientid": {"id":40002712},
    "productid": {"id":40002718},
    "clientorderid":1,
    "clientorderdate":"2017-01-01",
    "clientordervalue":23
  }
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to deserialize the JSON strings?

Comment: your desired JSON contains the additional 'ID' keys for client and product. These are not in your source.